# Safari iOS (iPod) not scaling precisely 2x

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design

I have a layout with a container that is exactly 300px wide. On my test iPod (iOS7) it renders at 608px, which is just slightly higher than 2x. I am using this meta tag to control the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-sale=1">
```

I though it could be related to padding/margin translation so to test I added a 200x200px box the to layout and it renders as 406px instead of the expected 400px.

Is there another variable that I'm not considering? This is really puzzling.

Comment: Not sure since I haven't make anything for iPod (only iPhone/iPad), but shouldn't be there a "width=device-width" too.

Comment: It would be better to provide a link. Is there any padding going on? Anyhow, "maximum-**sale**" isn't going to sell for much. ;-)